# Gunicorn not able to bind django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, gunicorn

I installed gunicorn inside virtual environment for running a django project in Ubutu 22 and tried to bind the project URL. But the below error appear and I am not able to bind. Can anybody please help me fix this error. Thanks

```
python --version
Python 3.10.12

(venv_django_proj) django@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/django_proj/django_proj$ gunicorn django_proj.wsgi
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25811] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25811] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (25811)
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25811] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25812] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25812
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25812] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/django/django_proj/django_proj/django_proj/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25812] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25812)
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25811] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2024-02-19 18:59:13 +0530] [25811] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not installed `Django` to your virtual enviroment. Install Django and other required packages for your project.

You can install django using this command:

`pip install django`

Comment: I have already installed django in the virtual environment and created a project and tested it by running the django development server.                 

(venv_django_proj) django@ubuntu-Virtual-Machine:~/django_proj/django_proj$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0.2
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.9.0

Comment: @SankarNarayanan you can see this error in logs. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'. you did not installed django

Comment: activate your enviremonet and install django again using pip install django. don't use sudo pip